# How can I optimize this jquery script?

Tags: jquery, optimization, click

I am a jquery "rookie" and I need a little clarification...
I have this form

```
<form id="myform">
    <div id="sectionA">
       <button id="button1">
    </div>
    <div id="sectionB">
       <button id="button2">
    </div>
    <div id="sectionC">
       <button id="button3">
    </div>
 </form>
```

To trigger the click on every button I do

```
$("#button1").click(function() { $("#myform").submit(); });
$("#button2").click(function() { $("#myform").submit(); });
$("#button3").click(function() { $("#myform").submit(); });
```

How can I write just only a single function to not duplicate for 3 times the same code ?
Thanks
Chri

Comment: Select all three buttons at once. Or, just make them all `type="submit"` and remove the javascript.

Comment: Do remember to close your buttons, they're not void elements.

Comment: Buttons already submit the form when clicked.

Comment: Is there any browser that doesn't submit a form when a nested button is clicked?

Comment: Sorry, change the button tags with 3 different images...this is my case. And if for any click I have to set a different valute on a hidden field how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can select multiple IDs with one selector.

```
$('#button1, #button2, #button3').click(function() {
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

This however can get clunky, so I would suggest using classes for the buttons you want to have this behavior.

```
<button class="clickable"></button>

$('.clickable').click(function() {
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button').click($('form').submit);
```